# Django Page not found (404) but URLs are correct

Tags: python, django

I encountered such an error, I get 404 error when trying to open the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/

```
# apps/account/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='account/login.html'), name="login")
]
```

And the strangest thing is that if I add something like 
qwe/ in path
http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/qwe it will work, and 2nd path login/ is working

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

```
#apps/account/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Hello</h1>')
```

Main urls.py

```
#project/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
                  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                  path('', include("apps.main.urls")),
                  path('account/', include("apps.account.urls")),
              ]
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggZNr.png)

Comment: "apps.account.urls" this should be "apps.accounts.urls"

Comment: your app name is accounts and you are using 'apps.account.urls' instead of 'apps.accounts.url'

Comment: Can you show screenshot of error

Comment: I apologize for my typo in the question, I already corrected it. Application called "account"

Comment: Which django version?

Comment: @Push_okkk Have you added LOGIN_URL and LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL options in settings.py?

Comment: Django version 3.0.3

Comment: @MehaParekh `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/account/profile'`

Comment: Please show `apps.main.urls`. Your error message is not about URL resolution - it's about data. Another view catches your `account/` URL and tries to fetch `article`s. Simple solution: change places of `apps.main.urls` and `apps.account.urls` includes.

Comment: @IvanStarostin thanks a lot, I had `path('<slug:slug>/', DetailView.as_view(model=Article, template_name="main/news.html"))` in apps.main.urls. And accounts/  was recognized as slug of some article.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work but I suggest you try a different import in account views.py.

Rather than below.

```py
#apps/account/views.py 
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
```

Try below

```py
#apps/account/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

Comment: The problem is that all works if I chang the path to something like `path('qwe/', views.index)` or something else. But when path is empty returns 404

Comment: Does this open. Notice no / in the end.    http://127.0.0.1:8000/account

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you are making to pages as your main page.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='account/login.html'), name="login")
]
```

here change the first path as

```
path('index/',views.index),
```

then try. This might work, because in your code you are pointing two path as main page so whenever you are including

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/qwe and path('qwe/', views.index)
```

the index page is pointing to the index page through path qwe.